# Get bundle product items in cart of Magento2

Tags: magento2, cart, bundled-product

I need to get bundle products from cart, and than I need to get the selected items of every bundle product. ?

Comment: Do you want to get it in a custom module?

Answer (score 1):

```
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

public function __construct(
    ...
    Session $session
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_session = $session;
    ...
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $items = $this->_session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
}
```